Error mongodb Json parameter disallowed in create mode
I am in mongodb Atlas Compass, with the mongosh terminal, Im trying to add a collection to Deportes database with a document included that adds a collection named Futbol. I succeded the first time but know it gives me an error.
I dont know if this is the code that succeded creating the collection because I started changing it, but it doesnt give me any syntax error and it says the initial error that appeared when it stoped working "parameter disallowed".
This is the error I get in mongosh.
MongoServerError: parameter Nombre is disallowed in create command
This is the code to create the collection and document.
db.createCollection( 'Futbol',
{
"Nombre": "Lionel Messi",
"Equipo": "Paris Saint-Germain",
"Número de camiseta": 30,
"Posición": "Delantero",
"Estadísticas":
{"Partidos Jugados": 782,
"Goles Totales": 672,
"Goles Promedio": 0.86,
"Asistencias": 286,
"Asistencias Promedio": 0.37,
"Títulos": 40}
}
)
This is the documentation that Im using to this code
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

The documentation you linked shows the valid options.  To insert a document, try using https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#db.collection.insertone--

thanks, but im trying to insert a collection with a document already in the parameters, i dont know if this is possible but i guess from the documentation I linked it was.

you can just have command db.Futbol.insertOne({ "Nombre": "Lionel Messi", "Equipo": "Paris Saint-Germain", "Número de camiseta": 30, "Posición": "Delantero", "Estadísticas": {"Partidos Jugados": 782, "Goles Totales": 672, "Goles Promedio": 0.86, "Asistencias": 286, "Asistencias Promedio": 0.37, "Títulos": 40} } )
As db.collection.insertOne creates the collection if it's not present.

With MongoDB it is not necessary to explicitly create the collection.  The database will create the collection automatically when you insert the first document.
